# How to make a view as always on top?

Tags: android, always-on-top, android-background

I have a `TextView` and it is on an image. When I click the button, `TextView`'s background color will change, but image won't disappear. For example:

My `TextView` at the beginning:

[image]

When I click a button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this using only one `TextView` then its may be not possible. So, I will suggest you to do this using `FrameLayout`. you can write your layout as below.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When you want to change the color behind the `TextView` then change the `ImageView` background as below...

```
ImageView mageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: But I want to change image(star) and background color dynamically. How can I make this?

Answer (score 1):

If it must be a TextView and an ImageView you could also wrap it within a FrameLayout (which is supposed to contain only one child). A FrameLayout will place all containing children elements on the same "place", so the get overlapped.

Or when you need more elements, you could also use a RelativeLayout and give your elements the same layout rules (e.g. all centered).

Answer (score 0):

You should use ImageView instead of TextView, the:

```
public void onClick(View v){
  imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: I have to use TextView :)

Comment: No problem, its the same code, only change imageView to TextView in my exmaple

Comment: But this is not provide what I want. When I use this the image(star) will disappear.

Comment: No, the start does not disappear, the background is back to the image

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton is better option for you.Image source will be star as u said.then onclick you change the background. if want set Text in this

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/any_drawable"
android:text="@string/any_text"
```